# Concatention of number and scalar in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying login in to all machines. So wrote a Perl script

```
my $i = 7;
while ($i < 20){
    my $key = "192\.235\.2\.$i.1 ";
    print $key;
    $i++;
}
```

which runs from `192.235.2.71` to `.191`. But concatenation failing here.

Comment: please explain it properly for better answers.

Comment: Please note that strings and numbers are both scalars.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use concatentation *within* a string. `$i.1` inside a double-quoted string will interpolate the value of `$i` but leave `.1` as it is. You could take the concatenation outside the string and write `'192.235.2.'.$i.'1'` (the dots don't need escaping). But it is easier to write `"192.235.2.${i}1"`. `${i}` is the same as `$i` but avoids the ambiguity with `$i1`.

If you want to print all the IP addresses from `192.235.2.71` to `192.235.2.191` in increments of ten, then consider

```
print join(' ', map "192.235.2.${_}1", 7 .. 19), "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using string concatenation but string interpolation, if you want to concatenate :

```
my $key="192.235.2." . $i . ".1 ";
```

If you want to achieve the same result with interpolation :

```
my $key="192.235.2.$i.1 ";
```

Anyway there is no need to escape the dot, you are not in a regex matching context ...

Comment: First code working with small with change : my $key="192.235.2." . $i . "1 ";